# Proof the E(x+y)=E(x)+E(y) using characteristic function

Tags: probability, probability-theory, expected-value, characteristic-functions

Let y be independent of x, then it holds that

$$E(x+y)=E(x)+E(y)$$ and also that
$$V(x+y)=V(x)+V(y)$$

[This](http://jse.amstat.org/v13n3/stein.html) blog proves both of these theorems. I'm curious if it is possible to prove the same using moments of the characteristic functions and the fact that
$$\phi_{x+y}(t) = \phi_x(t)\phi_y(t) = E[\exp(itX)]E[\exp(itY)]$$

Maybe something along the lines
$$E[x+y]=i^{-1}*\frac{d}{dt}(E[\exp(itX)]E[\exp(itY)]) = \dots = E[x]+[y]$$

Comment: But why, the title identity holds due to linearity :(

Comment: What does the ellipsis stand for?

Comment: $E(x+y)=E(x)+E(y)$ even when $y$ is not independent of $x.$ Delete [that equality from] your post.

Comment: @AnneBauval I think AlvinL means the ellipse between $i^{-1}*\frac{d}{dt}(E[\exp(itX)]E[\exp(itY)])$ and $E[x] + [y]$

Comment: You can definitely prove that theorem with characteristic functions; it is not a good approach and it gives you no insight, understanding or anything really, but it is possible (with some regularity assumptions on the characteristic function, such as differentiability).

Answer (score 1):

The relation $\mathbb E[x+y]=\mathbb E[x]+\mathbb E[y]$ holds always as
mentioned in the comments.

Proof of $\mathbb V[x+y]=\mathbb V[x]+\mathbb V[y]$:

From $\phi_{x+y}(t)=\phi_x(t)\phi_y(t)$ we get
\begin{align}
\frac{d}{dt}\phi_{x+y}(t)&=\phi_y(t)\frac{d}{dt}\phi_x(t)+\phi_x(t)\frac{d}{dt}\phi_y(t)\\
\frac{d^2}{dt^2}\phi_{x+y}(t)&=\phi_y(t)\frac{d^2}{dt^2}\phi_x(t)+\phi_x(t)\frac{d^2}{dt^2}\phi_y(t)+2\frac{d}{dt}\phi_x(t)\frac{d}{dt}\phi_y(t)\\
\end{align}
and therefore
\begin{align}
\mathbb E[(x+y)^2]&=-\frac{d^2}{dt^2}\Bigg|_0\phi_{x+y}(t)\\
&=
-\phi_y(0)\frac{d^2}{dt^2}\Bigg|_0\phi_x(t)-\phi_x(0)\frac{d^2}{dt^2}\Bigg|_0\phi_y(t)-2\frac{d}{dt}\Bigg|_0\phi_x(t)\frac{d}{dt}\Bigg|_0\phi_y(t)\\[2mm]
&=\mathbb E[x^2]+\mathbb E[y^2]+2\,\mathbb E[x]\,\mathbb E[y]\,.
\end{align}
Therefore,
\begin{align}
\mathbb V[x+y]&=\mathbb E[(x+y)^2]-\mathbb E[x+y]^2\\
&=\mathbb E[x^2]+\mathbb E[y^2]-\mathbb E[x]^2-\mathbb E[y]^2\\
&=\mathbb V[x]+\mathbb V[y]\,.
\end{align}